# CRUD: Método Listar

Tags: android, sqlite, objetos

Boa noite, estou aprendendo sobre CRUD no meu curso de programação mobile, estamos programando em um banco de dados SQLite, como o projeto ainda não está pronto por motivos do próprio professor, para checar se o Banco de Dados funciona, estamos colocando os dados na primeira tela que aparece no app (no caso a tela de apresentação) para carregar e assim os dados já serem gravados, porém como mostra a imagem, está dando erro no obj e eu não consigo entender o porque. Só da erro se for obj, qualquer outra coisa escrita não da erro. Eu já comparei o projeto com o projeto do professor, não encontrei o problema, o que pode ser?

[image: erro obj]

Comment: Por favor transcreva o código da imagem para facilitar na solução da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu tens erro nessa linha pois ja estás a instanciar uma variavel do tipo MediaEscolar na linha 33 e portanto no ciclo for deves usar outro nome. Tenta por exemplo assim e vê o resultado:

```
for(MediaEscolar media : objectos){
Log.d( "Matéria : " + media.getMateria() + " Semestre : " + media.getBimestre() + " Media :" + media.getMediaFinal())
}
```

Comment: Realmente, excluí os dados da linha 33 e no ciclo de baixo aceitou o nome. O jeito é colocar outro nome então. Obrigado pela ajuda :)